# Change XML node values from WiX

Tags: xml, wix

I want to be able to change an XML node value from WiX. The XML structure looks like this:

```
<settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <setting name="setting1">
        <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="setting2">
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">hello</value>
    </setting>
</settings>
```

I want to change the string value of setting2 to something else. I'm trying to use `XmlConfig` and the code that is not working looks like this:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id='SetSetting2' File='[#defaultSettings.xml]'
                Action='create' Node='value'
                ElementPath="//settings/setting[\[]@name='setting2'[\]]/value"
                Name='value' Value="test"
                On='install' PreserveModifiedDate='yes'
                VerifyPath="//settings/setting[\[]@name='setting2'[\]]/value/"/>
```

But this produces XML looking like this:

```
<setting name="setting2">
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string" value="test"></value>
</setting>
```

How do I make it look like the following?

```
<setting name="setting2">
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">test</value>
</setting>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try omitting the `Name` attribute. Like this:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id='SetSetting2' 
                File='[#defaultSettings.xml]'
                Action='create' 
                Node='value'
                ElementPath="//settings/setting[\[]@name='setting2'[\]]/@value"
                Value="test"
                On='install' 
                PreserveModifiedDate='yes'
                VerifyPath="//settings/setting[\[]@name='setting2'[\]]/@value/"/>
```

See also *[XmlConfig Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_xmlconfig.htm)*. For attribute `Name` it says:

> Not setting this attribute causes the element's text value to be set. Otherwise this specified the attribute name that is set.

Comment: I was certain I had tried this, but obviuosly I hadn't. Thanks, it works!

Comment: `@value` should just be `value`.